# Bijection between classes of maps from $S^n$ to $\tilde{X}$ and $S^n$ to $X$, where $p:\tilde{X} \to X$ is a convering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

> Let $n > 1$ and let $p:\tilde{X} \to X$ be a covering space, where $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ **are path-connected and locally path-connected**. Is there a bijection between $\mathrm{Classes}(S^n, \tilde{X}) $ and $\mathrm{Classes}(S^n, X)$, where $\mathrm{Classes}(A,B)$ denotes the homotopy classes of the continuous maps from $A$ to $B$.

I have tried to create this bijection using lifts: (since $S^n$ is simply-connected for $n > 1$, by the lifting criterion, every continuous map $f:S^n \to X$ admits a lift $\tilde{f}:S^n \to \tilde{X}$). Denote by $[f]$ the class of $f$ in $\mathrm{Classes}(S^n, X)$. The function I thought about was $$[f] \mapsto [\tilde{f}], $$ but this is not well-defined, as $f$ can have many lifts.

**EDIT:** I have added a few more assumptions that I forgot to write at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TMO took us 90% of the way there. Suppose you have a balloon, and you grab the southern hemisphere and squeeze it until all the air is pushed into the northern hemisphere, and the southern hemisphere is reduced to just a line segment. More formally, consider the map 
$$
(x, y, z) \mapsto (\alpha(z)x, \alpha(z)y, z)
$$
where 
$$
\alpha: [-1, 1] \to \Bbb R: t \mapsto \begin{cases} t^2 & t > 0 \\
0 & t \le 0 \end{cases} . 
$$
Then the image of the sphere ends up being the union of a line segment (the "string" on the balloon) and something that's topologically still a sphere.

Now instead of maps of your original sphere, you can consider maps defined on my collapsed balloon.

Sorry...I'm rambling here.

Suppose you have maps $F, G$ from the sphere to $X$. Let me refer to the south pole of the sphere as $S$. Lets say that $Q = F(S)$. If only $Q = G(S)$ as well, then $F$ and $G$ would be pointed-maps, and @TMO's comment would show they're homotopic. So I'm going to define a homotopy from $G$ to a map $G'$ where $G'(S) = Q$, and then we'll be done.

The idea is to gradually alter $G$ so that it's constant on the southern hemisphere, and then factor through a map to a balloon-and-string-like thing, and then alter G by a homotopy where the end of the string goes to $Q$. I'll need a path $\beta$ from $G(S)$ to $Q$, so $\beta(0) = G(S)$ and $\beta(1) = Q = F(S)$; that exists by path-connectedness. I'll use $\beta$ in a little while. First, let'd define homotopy number 1, using polar coordinates. Express each point of the domain $S^n$ as $(\sin(\phi) \mathbf{v}, \cos(\phi))$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^{n} \subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$. So $\phi$ corresponds to "latitude" in the 2-sphere, with $\phi = 0$ being the north pole, and $\phi = \pi$ being the south pole. OK. Let
$$
H_1((\sin(\phi) \mathbf{v}, \cos(\phi)), t) = \begin{cases}
F(\sin((1+t)\phi) \mathbf{v}, \cos((1+t)\phi)))) & (1+t) \phi \le \pi \\
F(S) & (1+t) \phi > \pi \end{cases}
$$
For $t = 0$, you can see that $H_1(P, 0) = F(P)$, so that's good. For $t = 1$, you can see that $H_1(P, 1)$ is constant on the southern hemisphere (i.e. $\phi \ge \pi/2$), and its value on the equatorial sphere is just $F(S)$. And $P \mapsto H_1(P, 1)$ is homotopic to $F$. I'm going to call that map $F'$.

Now I'm going to perform another homotopy: holding the value on the equatorial sphere to be $F(S)$, I'm going to drag the image of the south pole over to $Q$. Here goes: 
$$
H_2((\sin(\phi) \mathbf{v}, \cos(\phi)), t) = \begin{cases}
F(\sin(2\phi) \mathbf{v}, \cos(2\phi)) & \phi \le \pi/2 \\
\beta(t (\frac{2}{\pi}\phi - 1) & \phi > \pi/2 \end{cases}.
$$

Let's see what's going on in that second line. We have $\pi/2 \le \phi \le \pi$ in the southern hemisphere. Multiplying by $2/\pi$, we get $1 \le \frac{2}{\pi} \phi \le 2$; subtracting $1$ gets us a number that's $0$ at the equator and 1 at the south pole. 
We multiply by $t$, so when $t = 0$, the argument to $\beta$ is $0$, and $\beta(0) = F(S)$, which is great. In fact, for all $t$, when $\phi = \pi/2$, we end up computing $F(S)$. But as $t$ increases to $1$, the argument to $\beta$ gradually increases to something that ranges from $0$ to $1$ as $\phi$ varies from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$. And $\beta(1)$ is exactly $Q$.

So $H_2$ provides a homotopy from $F'$ to a new function $F''$ for which we have $F''(S) = Q$. And now @TMO's argument shows that $F''$ is homotopic-rel-basepoints to $G$, so we're done!

(Man, that's hard without a whiteboard!)

Answer (score 2):

Caution: I assumed that you were talking about pointed maps in my answer below. That is somehow the more natural thing to talk about here. The general case can be reduced to this one as can be seen in the very nice answer of @John hughes.

For $n = 1$ this is not true. Consider the standard covering $p \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ given by the exponential. Then we have that $[S^1,\mathbb{R}] = \pi_1(\mathbb{R}) = 1$ is a singleton whereas $[S^1,S^1] = \pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ is not.

For $n \geq 2$, the induced map $p_* \colon \pi_n(\tilde{X}) \rightarrow \pi_n(X)$ is an isomorphism. This follows for example from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of a fibration (if you don't know what a fibration is just think of a covering here (coverings are certains types of fiber bundles which are specific fibrations). So yes, we have such a bijection at least for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Oh, I have no knowledge of higher homotopy groups (the only thing I know about them is that they exist). Is there a proof that doesn't use there concepts? I imagine that it would be very complicated.

Comment: @user766825 Well, the $n$-th homotopy group is exactly the class that you are talking about. Homotopy classes of pointed maps from $S^n$ to $X$. Oh wait. Were you talking about pointed maps? Not sure if I happen to know a different proof though.

Comment: No, I was not referring to pointed maps, but maps and classes of maps in general.

Comment: Then I will have to think again I guess. I will still leave this answer here as it is maybe still interesting for others (or you at some point) that actually consider pointed maps, but it does no answer your question so far then. Under mild assumptions (would need to check again which ones exactly, but I guess just that $X$ is a "nice" topological space, i.e. something like a compactly generated weakly Hausdorff space) the class $[X,Y]$ corresponds to path-components of the space of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$ (with the compact-open topology). Maybe this could be helpful.

Comment: Which rises the question: Which category of topological spaces are you considering? Really all topological spaces or some "nicer" subcategory that you by abuse of notation just refer to as topologcial spaces again?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question. By "homotopy classes" I mean the following: Let $M(A,B) = \{f:A \to B \ \mid \ f \ \mathrm{ continuous} \}$. For $f,g \in M(A,B)$, I say that $f \sim g$ if there is some continuous function $F:A \times [0,1] \to B$ with $F(\cdot, 0) = f$ and $F(\cdot, 1) = g$. Then, $\mathrm{Classes}(A,B) = M(A,B)/\sim$. Then, $S^n$ is the $n-$sphere and $X$ is any topological space, with some covering space $\tilde{X}$.

Comment: Let me rephrase it then: The space $X$ that you are considering for your covering map, is that an arbitrary path-connected and locally path-connected space? Or do you have some other hidden assumptions on $X$ from your professor/lecturer/book/etc.?

Comment: Yes, it's just an arbitrary path-connected and locally path-connected topological space.

Comment: I think I am making this a lot more complicated than necessary at the moment. I would wait for another person to have a look at this that has a clearer mind right now, sorry. My mind just does not want to drop the assumption that the maps are pointed right now. I no one does so, I can also check later again.

Comment: I think I've addressed it by showing that any two maps  can be adjusted (by a homotopy) to maps that share a basepoint, which are then homotopic (rel basepoint) via your answer, hence homotopic via a combination of the two homotopies.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, thank you. I added that as a remark to my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

$p_* : [\mathbb{S}^n, \tilde{X}] \to [\mathbb{S}^n, X]$ does not have to be injective for $n \geq 2$ if you forget the basepoint.

For example for $n=2$, take $X$ the union of a sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and a diameter. Then for $\tilde{X}$ take the universal cover of $X$, which is a sequence of infinitely many spheres $\mathbb{S}^2$, where a sphere is connected to the next sphere with a line segment.

Then take $f,g : \mathbb{S}^2 \to \tilde{X}$ to be two maps that map to different spheres in the universal cover, then these two maps are not homotopic. However $p \circ f = p \circ g$, so the images are homotopic.